# How to prevent QPushButtons from changing their position while maximizing the window

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am making a kind of imageviewer in which we can see the histogram and hsv of the loaded image. Code is running as expected except whenever I am maximizing the window, all QPushButtons get misplaced.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

 class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
     super(Example, self).__init__()

     hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
     top = QtGui.QFrame(self)
     top.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
     bottomleft = QtGui.QFrame(self)
     bottomleft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
     bottomright = QtGui.QFrame(self)
     bottomright.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
     splitter1 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
     splitter1.addWidget(top)
     splitter2 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
     splitter2.addWidget(bottomleft)
     splitter2.addWidget(bottomright)
     splitter1.addWidget(splitter2)
     hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
     splitter1.setSizes([190,220])
     splitter2.setSizes([400,360])
     self.setLayout(hbox)
     QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))
     self.setGeometry(600, 120, 990, 850)
     self.setWindowTitle('PIMAD')
     self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('imag.jpg')) 
     self.show()
     browseButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Browse")
     browseButton.clicked.connect(self.loadFromFile)
     browseButton.setToolTip('click to <b>Browse</b>')
     histButton = QtGui.QPushButton("")
     histButton.setToolTip('For image <b>Histogram</b> click here')
     histButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('download.jpg'))
     histButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(55,35))
     histButton.clicked.connect(self.loadFromHist)
     hsvButton = QtGui.QPushButton("")
     hsvButton.clicked.connect(self.loadFromHsv)
     hsvButton.setToolTip('For <b>Image HSV </b> click here')
     hsvButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('hsv.jpg'))
     hsvButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50,35))

     self.lbl= QtGui.QLabel()
     self.lbl.setScaledContents(True)
     bottomleftLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
     self.lbl.setFixedSize(470, 480)
     self.lbl2 = QtGui.QLabel()
     self.lbl2.setScaledContents(True)
     bottomrightLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
     self.lbl3 = QtGui.QLabel()
     self.lbl3.setScaledContents(True)
     self.lbl3.setFixedSize(300,250)
     self.lbl3.move(650,05)
     self.lbl3.setParent(top)
     self.image = "C:\New folder (2)\logo.jpeg"
     self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap(self.image)
     self.lbl3.setPixmap(self.pix)    
     self.lbl3.show()
     topLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

     self.fileName = "\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\lord.jpg"
     self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.fileName)
     self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

     bottomleftLayout.addWidget(self.lbl)
     bottomleft.setLayout(bottomleftLayout)
     bottomrightLayout.addWidget(self.lbl2)
     bottomright.setLayout(bottomrightLayout)
     topLayout.addWidget(self.lbl3)

     topLayout.addStretch(1)

     top.setLayout(topLayout)
     topLayout.addStretch(1)

     browseButton.setParent(top)
     histButton.setParent(top)
     hsvButton.setParent(top)
     browseButton.move(720,260)
     histButton.move(790,260)
     hsvButton.move(860,260)
     browseButton.resize(60,40)
     histButton.resize(60,40)
     hsvButton.resize(60,40)
     browseButton.show()
     histButton.show()
     hsvButton.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('Example')
    main = Example()
    main.show()    
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using both layouts and absolute positioning (with method `move`), which is a bit weird. You also don't need to use `show()` that much. It's should only be called on the main window.

Absolute positioning usually don't work well if you want to resize your windows. It is meant to be fixed. The widgets will stay at the same position relatively to the top left corner of the window. If the windows becomes smaller, some widgets will be hidden, and if the windows becomes larger, the new space won't be used.

Layouts are meant to be flexible. You can arrange your widgets on vertical or horizontal lines (`QHBoxLayout` and `QVBoxLayout`) or on a grid (`QGridLayout`). Layouts will filled all the space available: they work on any window size.

I'd suggest you re-start from scratch by following a tutorial (a good one is ZetCode [Layout management in PyQt4](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/)). Try to start simple and progressively add more elements in your layout. Test at every steps to resize the window to see if it works as intended.

Comment: Actually I have to display two logos- one on top right and other on top left  and three QPushButtons on the bottom right of the top splitter but I have only managed to put logo on the top left and unable to display others.